# How to remove non alphabetic characters from words-ends

Tags: python

When I have a string "Mary's!!" I want to get "Mary's!", so only one non alphabetic character is removed at the beginning and/or the end of each word in the string, not in the middle of the word.

I have this so far in Python 3

```
import re
s = "Mary's!! string. With. Punctuation?" # Sample string 
out = re.sub(r'[^\w\d\s]','', s)
print(out)
```

This outputs:

```
"Marys string With Punctuation"
```

It removes everything, while it should be like this:

```
"Mary's! string With Punctuation"
```

Comment: split on spaces and string non-alphanumeric at the end?

Comment: What if the start and end of the string don't start with a non-alphabetic character?

Comment: Yes, split on spaces , at the end it depends if the word has two  non alphabetic characters  or more, just the last one should be removed.

Comment: I guess that word has no problem . Christian Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require that there is a space next to it (or start/end of string):

```
re.sub(r'(\s|^)[^\w\d\s]|[^\w\d\s](\s|$)', r'\1\2', s)
```

Or, alternatively with look-around:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\S)[^\w\d\s]|[^\w\d\s](?!\S)', '', s)
```

Comment: The look around appears to remove the apostrophes too. Is there any other way to do it with loops?

Comment: There was a typo in the second regex: it should be `(?<!` instead of `(?!<`.